# How to get rlwrap to work inside Emacs' shell / eshell?

Tags: shell, emacs, eshell, rlwrap

When I try to get `rlwrap` to work inside an Emacs (version 24.3.50.1) shell buffer (either `M-x shell` or `M-x eshell`), I get this error message:

> rlwrap: Oops, crashed (caught SIGFPE) - this should not have happened!

For example:

```
 rlwrap telnet google.com 80
```

wors fine from a regular terminal (like xterm), but crashes from a shell inside an Emacs buffer.

Several people are having similar issue but the only "answer" I could find so far is a "RTFM" style answer on mailing lists.  I did read that part of Emacs' doc and I don't understand what I'm supposed to do to make `rlwrap` work from within Emacs.

Comment: Why the downvote? By googling I can see that several people are having this issue.  Downvoter, do you know what *rlwrap* is?  Do you know what I'm doing wrong?  By the way this is Emacs, where every "configuration" is done programatically, so I don't see why this would be offtopic (most Emacs questions here are about "configuration"... Which are often answered by some *elisp* code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using <kbd>M-x</kbd>`ansi-term` instead of shell/eshell.

`shell` and `eshell` do not provide terminal emulation functionality, but `readline` requires terminal emulation capabilities to move the cursor etc.